# PHP-FFMpeg Installation and Basic Usage on windows issue

Tags: php, ffmpeg

following the [README](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/) I installed PHP FFmpeg through Composer and I downloaded binaries from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

now I'm trying to run the "Basic Usage" example:

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
?>
```

but i receive "Executable not found" errors because I didn't understand where to put them

I also tried specifying binaries ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe with:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/pathtobin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/pathtobin/ffprobe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
), $logger);
```

but still same error... am I making a mountain out of a molehill? any help is appreciated... Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I added ffmpeg\bin folder to system path and I can run executables from cmd from anywhere, but now I'm getting this error: `"Executable not found, proposed : avprobe, ffprobe"`... 
instead, if I give binary paths explicitly, I get `'ffprobe failed to execute command "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe" "-help" "-loglevel" "quiet"'`

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2**

**web server config**

- Windows 10 Pro
- IIS 10
- PHP 7.0.9

site root ---> `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\`
content:
- index.php
- input.mp4
- vendor/ (PHP-FFMpeg library folder)

FFmpeg binaries ---> `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FFmpeg\`
content:
- ffmpeg.exe
- ffplay.exe
- ffprobe.exe

**index.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffmpeg.exe',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffprobe.exe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
));
$video = $ffmpeg->open('input.mp4');
?>
```

**result**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffprobe.exe" "-help" "-loglevel" "quiet" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner.php(72): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->doExecutionFailure('"C:/inetpub/www...') #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary.php(209): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), Object(SplObjectStorage), false) #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary.php(137): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), false, NULL) #3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe\OptionsTester.php(61): Alchemy\Binary in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe\OptionsTester.php on line 63
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) say:

> This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. Be sure that these binaries can be located with system PATH to get the benefit of the binary detection, otherwise you should have to explicitly give the binaries path on load.

You will need to store these somewhere permanent and then add this path to your System or User PATH variable:

[image: Windows System Properties]

[image: System Path environment variable]

You would add ";c:\my\path\to\ffmpeg" to the end of the PATH value.

Comment: and then I can refer to the 2 binaries without specifying any path, as if they were always in the same folder of the page?

Comment: I added ffmpeg\bin folder to system path and I can run executables from cmd from anywhere, but now I'm getting this error: "Executable not found, proposed : avprobe, ffprobe"... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Miky correct, adding them to the path allows you to execute the binaries without specifying the absolute path. How are you running the PHP script?
 Have a look at this issue https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/172 - it may help.

Comment: what do you mean with How are you running the PHP script?

Comment: I mean are you running it from the command line or via a web server?

Comment: from cli I can run binaries from everywhere, but via web server the code posted gives me the errors above

Comment: I have to add ";c:\my\path\to\ffmpeg" to User PATH variable too?

Comment: Could you add the details of your web server config to your question?

Comment: No need to duplicate the PATH setting

Comment: Your config looks OK. What are the permissions on ffprobe.exe? BTW, not a good idea to store the executables in the public web directory.

Comment: of course, I'm just testing. I thought that could be the problem, so I tried giving full control to IIS user on bin folder but nothing changed

Comment: Understood. At this point I would put debugging statements in the PHP package and try to better figure out the context, e.g. which user it's running as,  what return code the executable is returning if anything, etc

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  Spent two days using procmon to determine why PHP wasn't starting ffprobe.exe on a new Windows 2016 install.

Turns out if your IIS AppPool identity doesn't have at least modify writes on the C:\Windows\temp folder, you will get this misleading error.

You can get the App Pool identity/context of your site using (not to be confused with the user context provided from get_current_user(). ):

```js
echo "Get ENV: ".getenv("APP_POOL_ID");
Or
echo "Get SERVER: ".$_SERVER["APP_POOL_ID"];
```

From my analysis, this is because PHP-CGI.exe, CMD.exe & the ffmpeg exe's (ffmpeg.exe, ffprobe.exe, ffplay.exe) use flat files in the temp folder to exchange and parse information.  When PHP-CGI.exe creates a temp file in this location all other processes can only read from the temp file, leaving it empty 0 bytes.  Every page load, I had these empty temp files being written to C:\Windows\Temp and ffprobe.exe would never execute.

Hope this helps someone.