# Problem when deploy NodeJS with FFMpeg to IIS server by IISNode

Tags: node.js, iis, ffmpeg, socket.io, iisnode

I have a nodeJs project stream RTSP to HTML.
I use rtsp-ffmpeg with socket io
server.js:

```js
var cams = arrData.map(function(device, index) {
            var config = JSON.parse(device.CauHinhThietBi);
            var rtspUri = getRtspUrl(config.IPLAN, config.RstpPort, config.Username, config.Password, streamType.MainStream);
            console.log(rtspUri);
            debugger;
            var stream = new rtsp.FFMpeg({input: rtspUri, rate: 25, resolution: '640x480', quality: 3});
            stream.on('start', function() {
                console.log('stream ' + device.TenThietBi + ' started');
            });
            stream.on('stop', function() {
                console.log('stream ' + device.TenThietBi + ' stopped');
            });
            return stream;
        });
    
        cams.forEach(function(camStream, i) {
            var ns = io.of('/cam' + arrData[i].ThietBiID);
            ns.on('connection', function(wsocket) {
                console.log('connected to /cam' + arrData[i].ThietBiID);
                var pipeStream = function(data) {
                    wsocket.emit('data', data);
                };
                camStream.on('data', pipeStream);
        
                wsocket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    console.log('disconnected from /cam' + arrData[i].ThietBiID);
                    camStream.removeListener('data', pipeStream);
                });
            });
        });
        
        io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            socket.emit('start', arrData);
        });
        
        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        });
```

When I run it in Visual Studio Code, It's well
But when I deploy to IIS with IISNode, Had below error:

> Error: FFMpeg executable wasn't found. Install this package and check
> FFMpeg.cmd property
> at ChildProcess. (D:\2. Demo\DemoNodeJs\DemoNodeJs\DemoNodeJs\node_modules\rtsp-ffmpeg\lib\rtsp-ffmpeg.js:118:10)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
> at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store these somewhere permanent and then add this path to your System or User PATH variable:

- in the Start Menu, right-click on Computer and choose Properties.
- Then select Advanced system settings.
- Open up the Environment Variables:

[image]

- And then edit the Path variable:

[image]

- The Path is just a list of folders that contain commands you’re allowed to use without typing in the full path of the exe files.

So, go ahead and add C:\ffmpeg\bin to the end of the line, making sure that there’s a semi-colon (;) after the previous folder:

[image]

[PHP-FFMpeg Installation and Basic Usage on windows issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521137/php-ffmpeg-installation-and-basic-usage-on-windows-issue)